# How can i edit the perticular row of HTML table using edit button in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

The following code is for fetching the data from database and showing them into HTML table

```
<?php

//Database connect file.
include 'connect.php';


$get_detail=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Wheel_Tag");

if ( mysqli_num_rows($get_detail) > 0)
    {session_start();

echo"<br><br><br><br>
<table border='6' style= 'background-color: #FFFFE0; color: #761a9b; margin: 2 auto;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>tag_title</th>
      <th>description</th>
      <th>show_in_welcome</th>
      <th>status</th>

    </tr>
  </thread>
  <tbody>";


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_detail))
        {
            $_SESSION['tag_title'] =$row['tag_title'];
            $_SESSION['description'] =$row['description'];
            $_SESSION['show_in_welcome'] =$row['show_in_welcome'];
            $_SESSION['status']=$row['status'];

          echo
                "<tr>
                    <td>{$_SESSION['tag_title']}</td>
                    <td>{$_SESSION['description']}</td>
                    <td>{$_SESSION['show_in_welcome']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['status']}</td>
                    <td><form action='edit.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tag_title' value='".$row["tag_title"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='edit' /></form></td>

  </tr>\n";        
      }

  }

    ?>
```

And here is my edit.php to edit the row

```
<?php
 session_start();


 echo"<form action='tag_show.php' method='post'>

 <div id='header'>
 <h1>Edit Your Profile</h1>
</div>
<div style='float:right; width:63%;'>

<br><br><br>

Tag Title<br><input name='tag_title' type='text' value='{$_SESSION['tag_title']}'><br><br>
Desciption<br><input name='description' type='text'value='{$_SESSION['description']}'><br><br>
 Show in welcome<br><input name='show_in_welcome' type='text' value='{$_SESSION['show_in_welcome']}'><br><br>
 Status<br><input name='status' type='text'value='{$_SESSION['status']}'>  <br><br>

 <input name='submit1' type='submit'  value='Update'>

 </form>";


 ?>
```

My problem is when I click on edit button the respective row value not come in the form of edit.php, instead of the last row value come by using session. Can anyone please solve my problem. I want the particular row value when I click on edit button.

Comment: Sorry, but what you are saying is not clear.

Comment: in simple words i want to edit the particular row of HTML table when i click on edit button.

Comment: in the tag_show.php i dont know how to edit the row of html table so i used the another page edit.php

Comment: You will need Ajax/JavaScript for this task.

Comment: You should use links instead of submit buttion

tag_show.php?editId=yourdbid

And you can add a back button to navigate to this page

Comment: I didn't understand , can you please explain me how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the form on you listing to just a link:

```
<td><form action='edit.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tag_title' value='".$row["tag_title"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='edit' /></form></td>
```

to:

```
<td><a href='edit.php?id={$row['tag_title']}'>{$row["tag_title"]}</a></td>
```

and than on the edit.php page make a mysql query to get the details about that single Wheel_Tag that you are loading, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Wheel_Tag WHERE tag_title = {$_GET['id']}
```

and display the elements.

If you want to save everything on SESSION so you don't make another request for the single Wheel_Tag on edit.php than you would need to store an array in $_SESSION which stores all the Wheel_Tags and than link the edit.php with the tag index on that array.

In general, there are a lot of issues with your code in regard to best practices. I would suggest you to start reading a book or a course about php and web in general.